# UINavigationController present a UINavigationController from bottom with sliding animation. How to hide status bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I custom the NavigationBar backgroundImage with a 320*44 image.So the status bar has black color.That's what I want.But,when I present a this navigationController,as you know,with default sliding animation from bottom,the status bar's black background is also here.How can I remove it while presenting UINavigationController's status bar is not change ?

Comment: give an screen shot here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20619259/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide your status bar from all view of your application. Then it is the better choice to set it from your application's '.plist' file. If you add the bellow line

```
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = false
```

in your '.plist' file then it will hide the status bar of you application.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add a key UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to Infor.plist and set value to YES. Then can hide/show status bar.

Add the following code to your view controller:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
    // iOS 7
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
} else {
    // iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks.